# Variable Id not increasing?

Tags: jquery

In the following code, the variable `Id` is not increasing with each loop
I updated it with my current code

Here is my code, thanks

```
(function (d, s) {
s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js';
(d.head || d.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function () {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var id = 158066137;;
        var link = 'http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId=' + id;
        function scan(val) {
            link = 'http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId=' + id;
            $.get(link, function (data) {
                var value = data;
                if (data.Creator.Id == 1 && data.Creator.Name == 'ROBLOX') {
                    var msg = "Created by " + data.Creator.Name + "\nObject Name " + data.Name + "\nAsset Id " + data.AssetId
                    console.log(msg);
                }
            });
        }
        setInterval(function() { scan(true); id++ }, 0);
    });
}
})(document);
```

Comment: I think `$(document).ready(...)` is running before jQuery is loaded, and `$` is defined to be something other than jQuery.

Comment: Your edit STILL includes the scope issue. You moved the var outside yes. but you initialize it to the SAME value everytime you call the function so it will never increment more than once.

Comment: @Sam you probably don't need to load jQuery dynamically. As long as the script tags aren't `async`, loading the different script pages sequentially will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the line `$(document)`, where `$` is referring some other library other than jQuery(which might be using `document.querySelectr()`).

So as a solution try to move your script to the `onload` handler of the dynamic script element like

```
(function (d, s) {
    s = d.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js';
    (d.head || d.documentElement).appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function () {
        //rever the value of $ to old one
        jQuery.noConflict();
        //use jQuery instead of $ to refer to jQuery object
        jQuery(function ($) {
            setInterval(function () {
                var id = 158066137;
                var link = 'http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId=' + id;
                $.get(link, function (data) {
                    var value = data;
                    if (data.Creator.Id == 1 && data.Creator.Name == 'ROBLOX') {
                        var msg = "Created by " + data.Creator.Name + "\nObject Name " + data.Name + "\nAsset Id " + data.AssetId
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                    id++;
                });
            }, 0);
        });
    }
})(document);
```

Comment: It's because `Id` is scoped to the anonymous function that is called by `setInterval` There by every time the function is called `Id` will be set to `158066137`

Comment: @Sukima Missed that part, my answer was handling the syntax error

Comment: Thanks; fixed the syntax error, can you please edit it to fix the scope problem? Also, any chance you have a guide on scope? I need practice with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your defining the `Id` inside the function that gets called via setInterval. First don't use setInterval especially if the function is spawning an ajax call. I think you want a setTimeout instead. but none the less let talk about the problem not the implementation choices.

```
// x => undefined
function foo() {
  var x = 1; // x => 1
  x++; // x => 2
}
foo(); // x => 2
foo(); // x => 2
foo(); // x => 2
// x => undefined
```

In the example above you never store the variable outside the scope of the function so it goes away and comes back new again.

```
// x => undefined
function foo() {
  var x = 1; // x => 1
  function bar() {
    x++; // x => x + 1
  }
  bar(); // x => 2
  bar(); // x => 3
  bar(); // x => 4
}
// x => undefined
```

So you see how calling the same function with a variable at a higher scope will do what you want.

```
function startPolling() {
  var x = 1;
  function next() {
    console.log(x++);
  }
  setInterval(next, 500);
}
```

Comment: @Sam He just explained how to fix it…

Comment: @Luxelin, thanks. was about to retort "WAT!" but SO needs a minimum of 12 characters to post. LOLz